# How to query all the fields in parent as well as child model related with a foreign key in DRF ? and how to apply pagination to the same dict?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, foreign-keys

**I have 3 models in this project**

```
class products(models.Model):  
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    userslikedproduct = models.ManyToManyField(UserAccount, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_id

class productReviews(models.Model):
    review_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(products, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date_added', auto_now_add=True)

class ReviewImage(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(productReviews, related_name='review_images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="/images/")
```

**I want to fetch all the reviews related to a product id along with review images.**

**I tried using**

```
Query1 = productReviews.objects.all().filter(product=product).values().order_by('-date_added')

Query2 = ReviewImage.objects.filter(review__product__product_id=product).values_list('review', 'image')
```

Query1 results in all the objects without images
Query2 reults  in all the images and review ids without review objects

**How can I fetch all the reviews of one particular product along with the review images?**

Here's my views.py file before being able to access the foreign key objects

```
class productReviews(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product = request.data.get('product', False)
        result = productReviews.objects.all().filter(product=product).values().order_by('-date_added')
        
        # Set up Pagination
        p = Paginator(result, 2)
    
      
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        

        try:
            page_obj = p.get_page(page)  
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            
            page_obj = p.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            
            page_obj = p.page(p.num_pages)
        context = {'page_obj': page_obj}


        print(context)
        samp_obj = page_obj.object_list
        print(samp_obj)
        a = page_obj.has_next()

        print(a)
  

       

        context = str(context)
   
        return Response({

                         'data': samp_obj,
                         'has_next_page': a,
                         
                         })
```

After using it from dict my views.py file

```
class productReviews(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product = request.data.get('product', False)
        
        
        
        reviews = productReviews.objects.all().filter(product=product).order_by('-date_added')
        print(reviews)
        
        reviews_as_dict = reviews.values()
        for review, review_dict in zip(reviews, reviews_as_dict):
            # Now you can get review images assigned to each review like this
            review_images = review.review_images.all()

            # Update the review_dict to include the review_image data
            review_dict['review_images'] = review_images.values()
            
        print(review_dict)


        # Set up Pagination
        p = Paginator(review_dict, 2)
    
      
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        

        try:
            page_obj = p.get_page(page)  
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            
            page_obj = p.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            
            page_obj = p.page(p.num_pages)
        context = {'page_obj': page_obj}


        print(context)
        samp_obj = page_obj.object_list
        
        a = page_obj.has_next()

       
       

        
   
        return Response({
                         'data': samp_obj,
                         'has_next_page': a,
                         
                         })
```

But now I am unable to use dict object in pagination

How do I apply pagination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `values` or `values_list`. That makes your objects into Python dicts, or lists.

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```py
# To get all reviews
reviews = product.reviews.order_by('date_added')

# To get all reviews as Python dicts
reviews_as_dict = reviews.values()

for review, review_dict in zip(reviews, reviews_as_dict):
  # Now you can get review images assigned to each review like this
  review_images = review.review_images.all()

  # Update the review_dict to include the review_image data
  review_dict['review_images'] = review_images.values()
```

This should give you a list of dicts which should look like:

```py
[
  {
     ... other review attributes,
     review_images: [
        {
          ... ReviewImage attributes
        }, ...
     ]
  }, ...
]
```

However, this seems kind of unnecessary. If you're passing this data to a template, you could just add the first `reviews` variable to the context and use it in the template like so:

```
<div>
  {% for review in reviews %}
    <h1>Review {{ review.review_rating }}</h1>
    <small>Description {{ review.review_desc }}</small>
    
    <h3>Review images for this review</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for review_image in review.review_images.all %}
         <li><img src="{{ review_image.image.url }}"></img></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank You,
But it is giving error

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'review_images'

Comment: Are you still using `values` or `values_list`? The relation is only available through the model instance, not through the "primitive" Python objects you get by using `values` or `values_list`.

Comment: If you really need to use them store the output of these in another variable.

Comment: I removed ```values``` 
Now I am getting image objects only, but  I want to use them together with reviews in pagination
How can I do that?

Comment: I will edit my answer to provide a more complete example, just a sec

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to get all the values in ```review_dict```. But, I am unable to use Paginator in views.py. I am not passing this to a template. I need to create APIView

Comment: This answer solved my issue of accessing attributes related by a foreign key. I further need to use pagination on this. Can you help me? or should I post a new question?

Comment: You should probably mention that you're using Django Rest Framework. It makes a lot of difference

Comment: Since you're using the DRF, I would suggest first using the [model serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) provided by the DRF out of the box, that would maybe solve your issues with the pagination. The pagination issue might require another question, not sure.

Comment: Maybe just modify the question and add your views.py

Comment: I have modified the question and added the views.py file. Is it okay? or should I post a new question?

Comment: It looks like you're adding a parenthesis in the line where you define the `Paginator`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo because I tried using ```list(review_dict)``` inside ```Paginator``` ,  but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you describe better what is not working with the pagination?

Comment: When I am trying to use pagination on the ```review_dict``` it gives me the error```unhashable type: 'slice'```. When I use ```list(review_dict)``` it returns only field names and not field values. And also the ```review_dict``` consists of one review object only instead of appending all the previous objects. May be I need to somehow append the previous objects in the for loop.

Comment: From your code, I see that your view should return `review_dicts`, not a single `review_dict`. Have you tried passing that to `Paginator` initializer. You need to pass a list of dicts to the Paginator, not only one dict

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a genius. I got the expected result.